# EDGE Browser behaves differently when application opened in different tabs

Tags: web-applications, smartgwt, microsoft-edge

I am working for Java-smartGWT application. I have two instances of my application in different tabs of Edge browser.

suppose I have:
i) http://192.23.230.21:8085/myAPP1 - 1st instance - 1st tab
ii) http://192.23.230.21:8086/myAPP1 - 2nd instance - 2nd tab

I have opened both the applications in two tabs of Edge browser like showing above.

In my application I have two modules(myAPP1 and myAPP2) and I have an option to redirect from myAPP1 to myAPP2 by clicking on a link. Currently I opened 2 tabs with myAPP1 in Edge browser.

From (i) - 1st tab: http://192.23.230.21:8085/myAPP1 --> opening myAPP2 opens in a new tab(3rd tab) by clicking on a link(myAPP2)

From (ii) - 2nd tab: http://192.23.230.21:8086/myAPP1 -->opening myAPP2 opens in a new tab(3rd tab) clicking on a link(myAPP2) - which is refreshing opened "http://192.23.230.21:8085/myAPP2" in 3rd tab and reloaded as "http://192.23.230.21:8086/myAPP2"

Expected result: When the user opens myAPP2 from the 2nd tab(From (ii)), it should be opened in a new tab(4th tab) but not in the existing 3rd tab(which is opened From (i)).

This behavior is only in Edge browser, worked properly in the other major browsers. 
Could any body give me suggestion about how to resolve this?

Comment: Please let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML rendering this link includes the standard `<a href target="_blank"/>` this link should open in new tab everytime you click it